# Using apoc.periodic.iterate to create new relationships based on calculation in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I am very confused with apoc.periodic.iterate, I have used it successfully in the following query between (s1) and (s2)  to create a new link [r:ALL_TRANSFERRED] :

```
//CREATE WEIGHTED LINK
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (s1)-[:TRANSFER]->(s2) WHERE s1 <> s2 RETURN s1,s2", 
"MERGE (s1)-[r:ALL_TRANSFERRED]->(s2) ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1 ON MATCH SET r.weight = r.weight + 1"
, {batchSize:5000, parallel:false,iterateList:true})
```

But when I am trying to modify the weight, to add a calculation based on a new variable, it creates some extra nodes? Let's assume that (s1) and (s2) are schools which have relationships with teachers, so I want to count all teachers in a school as a new variable called *teachers_in_school*, which can be used in this calculation. I am trying:

```
//CREATE NORMALISED WEIGHTED LINK 
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (s1)-[:TRANSFER]->(s2) WHERE s1 <> s2 
WITH s1,s2
MATCH (t:Teacher)-[:HAD]->(c:Contract)-[:WITH]->(s1)
WHERE c.end = 2016
RETURN s1, count(distinct t) as teachers_in_school", 
"MERGE (s1)-[r:ALL_TRANSFERRED]->(s2) ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1 ON MATCH SET r.weight = (r.weight + 1)/teachers_in_school"
, {batchSize:5000, parallel:false,iterateList:true})
```

But I get some extra nodes with empty lables linked to (s1) and (s2), and no link [r:ALL_TRANSFERRED] between them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your first `iterate` statement was not returning the `s2` nodes, so the second statement ended up creating brand new `s2` nodes.

The following query's first statement returns an `s2s` collection that contains all the `s2` nodes for each `s1`. It also counts the teachers for each `s1` just once. The second statement uses `UNWIND` to break up `s2s` into individual nodes so that they can be processed individually.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (s1)-[:TRANSFER]->(s2) WHERE s1 <> s2 
   WITH s1, COLLECT(s2) AS s2s
   MATCH (t:Teacher)-[:HAD]->(c:Contract)-[:WITH]->(s1) WHERE c.end = 2016
   RETURN s1, s2s, COUNT(DISTINCT t) as teachers_in_school", 
  "UNWIND s2s AS s2
   MERGE (s1)-[r:ALL_TRANSFERRED]->(s2)
   ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1
   ON MATCH  SET r.weight = (r.weight + 1)/teachers_in_school",
  {batchSize:5000, parallel:false,iterateList:true}
)
```